# Implementing Multi-File Programs in Vitsy

Tags: java, stack, interpreter, dynamic-loading, language-design

I'm the proud owner of the [Vitsy programming language](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), which I've been working on for some time (except recently, because high school). It's only been used in PPCG so far, but I hope to expand it to more useful things. It is a top-access-only 2-dimensional stack-based language that moves in multiple directions through Vitsy code with the ability to use other "classes". The only problem is that, a lot of the time, the way I have been loading these "classes" is extremely inefficient, terribly written, and shoddily thought out.

Here is an [excerpt](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy/blob/5fda54f58463a070a56e504ed02eac6c03c761c9/src/com/VTC/vitsy/Vitsy.java#L98) that I would like to be reviewed:

```
public static void methodHandler(int source) throws InterruptedException, IOException, ScriptException {
    olddir.add(direction);
    direction = true;
    if (source == -1) {
        oldpos.add(new Integer[]{currin,position});
        currin = top().intValue();
        position = 0;
        rmtop();
        while (position < currin().length && !ending) {
            if (!looping.get(looping.size()-1) && position > currin().length - 1) {
                break;
            }
            else opHandle();
            position = (direction) ? (position + 1): (position - 1 >= 0) ? position - 1: currin().length-1;
        }
        currin = oldpos.get(oldpos.size()-1)[0].intValue();
        position = oldpos.get(oldpos.size()-1)[1].intValue();
        oldpos.remove(oldpos.size()-1);
        direction = olddir.get(olddir.size()-1);
        olddir.remove(olddir.size()-1);
        ending = false;
        return;
    }
    instruct.add(FileHandler.getFileInstruct(new String[]{(source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-1):users.get(users.size()-1)[source]}, new boolean[]{false, false}));
    users.add(FileHandler.getFileInstruct(new String[]{(source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-1):users.get(users.size()-1)[source]}, new boolean[]{true, false}).get(0));
    extender.add(FileHandler.getFileInstruct(new String[]{(source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-1):users.get(users.size()-2)[source]}, new boolean[]{false, true}).get(0)[0]);
    oldposext.add(new Integer[]{currin, position});
    currin = (source == -2)?currin:top().intValue();
    currclassname.add((source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-2):users.get(users.size()-2)[source]);
    position = 0;
    if (source != -2) rmtop();
    while (position < currin().length && !ending) {
        if (!looping.get(looping.size()-1) && position > currin().length - 1) {
            break;
        }
        else if (!currin()[position].equals(""))
            opHandle();
        position = (direction) ? (position + 1): (position - 1 >= 0) ? position - 1: currin().length-1;
    }
    instruct.remove(instruct.size()-1);
    currin = oldposext.get(oldposext.size()-1)[0].intValue();
    position = oldposext.get(oldposext.size()-1)[1].intValue();
    oldposext.remove(oldposext.size()-1);
    currclassname.remove(currclassname.size()-1);
    direction = olddir.get(olddir.size()-1);
    olddir.remove(olddir.size()-1);
    ending = false;
}
```

Relevant variable declarations:

```
private static boolean direction = true;

private static int position = 0;

private static ArrayList<Integer[]> oldpos = new ArrayList(0);

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> instruct = new ArrayList(0);

private static ArrayList<Integer[]> oldposext = new ArrayList(0);

private static ArrayList<String> extender = new ArrayList(0);

private static ArrayList<String[]> users = new ArrayList(0);

private static ArrayList<String> currclassname = new ArrayList(0);

private static ArrayList<Boolean> olddir = new ArrayList(0);

private static boolean ending = false;

private static int currin = 0;
```

This is very spaghetti-like code, and is part of a major Vitsy reworking. The main problems I seek assistance in is 1) adhering to convention (which I certainly haven't), 2) attempting to increase the efficiency of the class loading and method calling, and 3) general tips on how to think about these concepts in the future.

Example usage in Vitsy:

Let's say I have two files, `Vitsy` and `Hello`:

Vitsy

```
iG 00k Z

;u Hello
```

Hello

```
" olleH"
```

In the program Vitsy, I get the name of the current class (`i` pushes -1 when there is no string input through CLAs and `G` gets the name of the referenced class, `-1` referring to itself). Then, I call the 0th line index of the 0th index of the use declaration (`;u Hello`, meaning that I call the first line in the 1st use declaration, the file "Hello"). This means that I now have "Hello Vitsy" on the stack. I now use `Z` in the file Vitsy to output everything in the stack.

However, this simple task is *seriously inefficient* as of now, as, during these steps, I have to load the "Hello" file, execute the line of code I seek (saving all the information about where I was and stuff from the first program), unload the program, and continue. This would be a problem if I had to, say, call many different classes, and would take far longer than should be necessary.

Comment: And I posted this way too late. x.x It is quite late for me, so if I don't respond immediately, do not be alarmed - I'm around.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Great job on your first question!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I've replaced your artificially excessively commented code with the real code in GitHub, so that we may do a realistic review.

Comment: @200_success Thank you! I'll remember that for my future posts, sorry!

Comment: @Heslacher I added all the used variables' declarations to the question. c:

Comment: About this apparent [Easter egg](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy/blob/master/src/com/VTC/vitsy/FileHandler.java#L23) — is that some kind of provision for winning a future "99 Bottles of Beer" code golf challenge?

Comment: @200_success That was about winning a [_past_ "99 Bottles of Beer" challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64220/44713).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this looks like golfed code :)

It's never a pleasure to review spaghetti code. So I won't give a comprehensive review, with luck somebody else will, or we can each improve some bits and pieces. So here are a few suggestions to get you started.

#### Spacing

Use more whitespace in general. Not excessively, but more. Paste your code in an IDE, and use the auto-reformat feature. It will add spaces around operators, and the code will become easier to read.

Then add some vertical space. This means empty lines, to separate chunks of code that are only loosely related, and keep lines together that are closely related. Each group of lines (not separated by empty lines in between) should form a cohesive unit, doing some logical step.

As a next step, add a comment above each group of lines to explain the logical step they accomplish.

As a next step, extract reach group of lines to a helper method, converting the comment to a method name.

#### Other specific tips

Given this:

```
instruct.add(FileHandler.getFileInstruct(new String[]{(source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-1):users.get(users.size()-1)[source]}, new boolean[]{false, false}));
users.add(FileHandler.getFileInstruct(new String[]{(source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-1):users.get(users.size()-1)[source]}, new boolean[]{true, false}).get(0));
extender.add(FileHandler.getFileInstruct(new String[]{(source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-1):users.get(users.size()-2)[source]}, new boolean[]{false, true}).get(0)[0]);
oldposext.add(new Integer[]{currin, position});
currin = (source == -2)?currin:top().intValue();
currclassname.add((source == -2)?extender.get(extender.size()-2):users.get(users.size()-2)[source]);
```

If I'm looking at this right (it's hard to see in the jumble), all these lines depend on the condition `source == -2`. Not only it's a waste to evaluate that multiple times unnecessarily, this is very hard to read.

Instead of repeating an ugly ternary on all these lines, rewrite as a proper if-else.

#### Refactoring spaghetti code

It's ok to make small steps that may seem insignificant at first. As the code gets cleaner bit by bit, more and more improvement opportunities become clear, gradually leading to more substantial improvements.

My tips so far don't change the logic of your code. When you start changing the logic, later, as you make progress with cleaning, how will you know you're not breaking something? You *can* know (almost), by writing unit tests first, covering all execution paths. After that you can go on and refactor boldly yet fairly safely, re-running the unit tests after every refactoring step. Without automated tests, verifying the behavior using manual testing will be a nightmare.

Martin Fowler has a famous book on refactoring techniques. That should help a lot.

Comment: Should I update my question with the changes?

Comment: Also, this code could be _much_ more golfed - I tried to avoid golfing it as much as possible. ;D I have a tendency to golf my code by accident, as I golf in Java, Vitsy, AppleScript and MineCraft frequently.

Comment: Understood, no worries. No, don't update the code in the question, that would invalidate my answer. Wait a bit for further suggestions by other users. A few days later, you may want to post a new question with your revised code. This is how we do it around here and it works well, but it may require a bit of patience.

Comment: *thumbs up* Well, post-modification looks much better already. :D Thanks.